# Сломался Bootstrap (не адаптирует)

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="slogan col-2 col-md-2 bg-info">Smallapps</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему он не адаптирует под все устройства?

Answer (score 3):

Допишите в `head` мета тег `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Зачем копировать мой ответ?

Comment: я не копировал, когда оставлял свой ответ, других не было

Comment: @Vadizar, он прав - во время написания ответа твой был удалён.  Также напоминаю, что пользователи с репутацией меньше 10К вообще не видят удалённые сообщения. Да и даже если бы видели, правильный ответ не должен оставаться удалённым. Поставил тебе плюс.

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему решит данный тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```